# Вывод двумерного массива (PHP) через два выпадающих списка 

Tags: массивы, php, select

Всем привет.
Задача: показать пользователю два выпадающих списка (вывод второго на основании первого).

Пример: пользователь выбирает название улицы (выпадающий список) и ему в соседнем выпадающем списке показываются номера домов, которые есть именно на этой улице.

Вот собственно массив:
`<?
$mkr = array ("4 МКР-Н" => array(19, 20, 23, 24), "5 МКР-Н" => array(1, 6, 7, 11));
?>`

Comment: гугл + связанные select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов реализации может быть много. Например:

Выводишь первый селект с улицами

```
<select class="streets">
    <?foreach($mkr as $k => $v){?>
        <option value="<?=$k?>"><?=$k?></option>
    <?}?>
</select>
```

Выводишь все возможные селекты выбора номера. Все они по дефолту скрыты (style="display: none")

```
<?foreach($mkr as $k => $v){?>
    <select style="display: none" class="numbers" data-street="<?=$k?>">
        <?foreach($v as $n){?>
            <option value="" data-number="<?=$n?>"><?=$n?></option>
        <?}?>
    </select>
<?}?>
```

Добавляешь обработчик на событие смены опции у первого селекта. При каждой смене берется value выбранной опции. Затем скрываются все селекты с номерами и показывается один с выбранным data-street. Для данного куска js кода необходима библиотека jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('.streets').on('change', function(){
            var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
            var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();

            $('.numbers').hide();
            $('.numbers[data-street="'+valueSelected+'"]').show();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, mJeevas.
А чисто на php это реализовать можно (без JS)?

Comment: @Roman45, как уже сказали, вариантов реализации очень много.  
Для вывода связанного списка можно сделать вот что:

    <?
    $key = $_GET['key']; // Выбранная улица, допустим "5 МКР-Н"

    print 'Выберите номер дома на улице ' . $key . ':<br />';
    print '<select name="nums">';
    foreach($mkr[$key] as $v)
      print '<option value="' . $v . '">№' . $v . '</option>';
    print '</select>';